# Android global LocationManager access(like singleton)

Tags: java, android

In my Android application, I have different activities with similar lists of addresses & I need to show (update) distances (in km) to them at least in a 10 s interval. But I don't know the right way to organize fast access to an actual current location from any activity anytime.

If I overload splash screen activity with `LocationManager` methods & store current coordinates in the `Application` object & call some `((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).getCurrentPos()` from the activity to get the current position, will it be correct way for solving this problem? 
Or should I create singleton & initialize it in `Application.onCreate()` method? Or how?

Comment: *If I overload Application class with LocationManager* It doesn't make sens ... where you will ask user for permission? ... also asked bazillion times: why don't you use service?

Comment: If I create service, than I should manage it's lifetime from all activities onStop()/onResume() because I need it only when application is active. Isn't it too complex always starting & stopping service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the same issue by using custom singleton location manager class.

The my location manager is inicialized with application context and it contains implementations needed by GoogleApiClient for LocationService API (i'm using FusedLocation API).

If you inicialize the custom location manager in your splash (you can also handle required permissions for Android 6.0 and above here), then in other Activities simple call code like this to access current position:

```
MyLocationManager.getInstance().getCurrentPos();
```

Comment: Next problem I faced is correct stopping of location manager. One solution I found is to get location once & remove listener in `onLocationChanged(Location location)` and next is to stop manager in every activity's `onStop()` method. What was your solution?

Comment: In my case I need the location till the application is running, so I add listener in splash and remove it on application exit. But If you want to remove listener in every activity's onStop(), you don't need the solution with custom singleton location manager.

Comment: What do you mean under "remove it on **application exit**"? this is the most interesting point.

Comment: `MyLocationManager `is registered as listener to obtain location updates. On application exit you should call some method on  `MyLocationManager `, which unregister this listener from LocationManager or LocationService - `removeUpdates()` in case of LocationManager. The "application exit" means when user made back press in the main Activity in activity stack.

Comment: I have also solution if you want to remove location listener when your application is on background. But detection if application is running on background is another case

Comment: Well, the first thing that indicates that app in background is call of `onStop()` but if application has lots of activities and only few of them uses coordinates, in this case you should stop your `MyLocation` in every `onStop()` method and this is not quite "elegant" solution I think. I'm looking for solution with simple lifetime management.

Comment: Ok, in your case will be better to add methods to register and unregister `MyLocationManager` as location listener. Then you can register it in `onResume()` and unregister in `onPause()` in every Activity, which needs the current position.